# ogr2ogr -where: match features from OSM PBF with unset "seasonal" field

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, ogr

I have an .osm.pbf file from Geofabrik and want to extract all lakes that are not seasonal or intermittent to an SHP file, using `ogr2ogr`. I am currently using the following command:

```sh
ogr2ogr -where "((natural = 'water' and water = '') or (water in ('lake', 'oxbow')) and intermittent = 'no' and seasonal = '')" outfile.shp infile.osm.pbf multipolygons
```

The resulting SHP file is empty. If I remove the `seasonal` bit from the `-where` query, I get the desired features into the output files, but also others that *are* seasonal.

I took a look at the PBF file in QGIS, and there the `seasonal` field is showing as `NULL`. How do I need to modify my `-where` query to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `seasonal` field is showing as `NULL`, you should check for `seasonal IS NULL` in the `-where` query, like this:

```
"((natural = 'water' and water = '') or (water in ('lake', 'oxbow')) and intermittent = 'no' and seasonal is NULL)"
```

Best to verify if the `water` field is in the same situation...

Comment: I tried that exact command, but using `=` instead of `is` for the `NULL` check - does that make any difference ?

Comment: In any case, this works ! :)

Comment: An explanation why `= NULL` doesn't work can be found here: [SQL IS NULL vs = NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581745/sql-is-null-and-null)